# how to use QtAndroid::startActivity

Tags: android, qt

the new Qt Android extra has a new function. QtAndroid::startActivity

I don't know how to set the fisrt parameter in C++ code. Can someone give me an example?Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You must build a JNI object containing an Android "Intent" object. Creating an Intent object is fairly easy in Java, but I have no idea how to do it from C++.

So, my solution is to add a .java file to my Qt project and create a little helper function in Java that will generate and return an Android Intent object for me:

```
package com.k9spud.FileBrowser;

import java.io.File;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AndroidAction
{
    public static Intent openFile(String filePath, String fileType)
    {
        File f = new File(filePath);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, fileType);
        return intent;
    }
}
```

(you can read more about Android Intents here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)

Now that I have my Java helper function, I can issue a JNI call from my C++ code to use my helper function. The Java code will generate the desired Intent object and I'll finally be able to use QtAndroid::startActivity().

Here is a C++ function I use for opening (viewing) files in external Android apps:

```
void openFile(QString filePath, QString fileType)
{
    QAndroidJniObject jfilePath = 
    QAndroidJniObject::fromString(filePath);
    QAndroidJniObject jfileType = 
    QAndroidJniObject::fromString(fileType);
    QAndroidJniObject intent = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("com/k9spud/FileBrowser/AndroidAction",
                                                                     "openFile",
                                                                     "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;",
                                                                     jfilePath.object<jstring>(),
                                                                     jfileType.object<jstring>());

    QtAndroid::startActivity(intent, 0);
}
```

To show a video file for example, I call my C++ openFile() function passing the full path to the desired file and the MIME type which indicates to Android which apps should be presented as possible ways to view this file:

```
openFile("/storage/emulated/legacy/Movies/myvideo.mp4", "video/mp4");
```